Can't disable power notifications in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm using a wireless game pad that seems to trigger low battery notifications every ~20 mins for some reason. Since I noticed battery notifications were spammy and generally very inaccurate, I tried looking for a toggle to turn them off and didn't find it.

I found this post showing that there should be a power notification toggle in notification settings, however that doesn't exist in my notification settings page.
I'm not sure if the toggle was moved elsewhere or if something is broken.
